# Algolia browse function not accepting filters

Tags: algolia

I am using the `browse` function on results more than 1000.

I am passing `facetFilters` in the first `index.browse` call. This returns a `cursor`. I then use this `cursor` in my `index.browseFrom` function.

This returns a result which I think is correct, however, `nbHits` and `nbPages` are not shown in the returned response.

Below is what I am trying to do:

```
index.browse(keyword, {
   hitsPerPage: 20,
   facetFilters: 'category:testCategory AND brand:testBrand'
}, function (err, content) {
   index.browseFrom(content.cursor, function (err, content) {
     vm.results.listings = content.hits;
     vm.results.totalResults = content.nbHits;
     vm.results.pages = content.nbPages;
     vm.results.hitsPerPage = content.hitsPerPage;
     vm.noResults = (content.hits == 0);
     vm.loading = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance reason, the `nbHits` & `nbPages` attributes are not computed during a `browse`: it has really been designed to iterate over the whole content of an index.

If this is used for end-users, you can go for a "Load more" button instead of a regular pagination.

Comment: When i add a page number from 60 and uses `browse` the `cursor` remains the same and I don't get the results for page 60. I am using `browseFrom` but the cursor is the same whatever page I pass in the parameter

Comment: Yes the page parameter is not used while using browse -> the only way to use browse is to go from one cursor to another reading the "cursor" attribute in the JSON answer.